# regex remove link but not inside an img tag

Tags: php, regex

I run a mailing site. I set up regex to replace links in the body of html email.

I use:

```
// remove entire anchors

$body=preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU','[Link Removed]', $body);

// remove links not wrapped in an anchor tag

$body= preg_replace('!((?:www|http://)[^ ]+)!', '[Link Removed]', $body);
```

The problem I have is when there is an image placed in the html. The img src, of course, gets replaced with [Link Removed] and a broken image shows in the email. I do not want a link to be replaced if it is the src of an image.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$body= preg_replace('~(?<!src=["\'])(?:www|http://)[^ ]+~', '[Link Removed]', $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're aware of the problems associated with processing HTML with regular expressions? Unfortunately PHP has no simple alternative

If you use a negative look-behind you can ignore URLs inside a `src` attribute

In addition the `www` option has to be enhanced to `(?<!/)www` (`www` not preceded by a slash)

This will do what you want

```
$body= preg_replace('_(?<!src=["\'])(?:http://|(?<!/)www)\S+_', '[Link Removed]', $body);
```

But notice that there is nothing to prevent character references being used as delimiters for attribute values, so an image could look like

```
<img src=&#34;http:www.mysite.com/image.png&#34;>
```

but clearly this is unlikely

Comment: Excellent guys! Thanks! Regex is like Chinese to me and I don't use Chinese enough to learn it! Both ways worked to suit my purposes ;-) I appreciate your time! include @xdazz